# Function that binds new rows in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, append, rows

I am relatively new to R and need to create a function in which after each call, a dataframe will have appended to it another row.

This is what the empty dataframe should be (aka title of its rows):

```
 Percent Category Word
```

The function is

```
output <- function(category, word)
```

which will in the end calculate a percent based on these words.

So, for instance, category(Lung, Female) would output a percent of 51, and hence the resulting dataframe would be

```
Percent Category Word
51      Lung     Female
```

If I were to rerun the function with, let's say category(Blood, Male), whose percent is 71 I would like the resulting dataframe to be

```
Percent Category Word
51      Lung     Female
71      Blood    Male
```

and I would essentially want to run the function as many times as I would want, appending rows continuously. However, the dataframe is only local and not global so when I run the function and if I were to output the dataframe just that row appears in the console but nothing shows up in my global environment. This is what I have (omitting the beginning of the fxn that calculates percent):

```
output <- function(category, word)
{
    row <- data.frame(percent, category, word)
    # row <- rbind(row, row) # I don't know...
    return (row)
}
```

Given that the function calculates a percent variable, how would I create a dataframe accessible from the global environment where this function appends rows to it? Should I create a dataframe in the global environment and then try it out?

Comment: You ca do it outside the function with `df <- rbind(df, output("Lung", "Female")) `

Comment: @HubertL's suggestion should work, but appending rows one-by-one is often much slower in R than other approaches. If your data is big enough that you're running into speed issues with this approach, you can probably ask a new question asking for help improving it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `nrow` to count the number of rows of the data.frame.

```
df<-data.frame(percent=as.numeric(), category=as.character(), word=as.character(), 
stringsAsFactors = F) #setting up empty data.frame

output <- function(df,category, word){ 
  percent<-12 #fictious percentage
  df[nrow(df)+1,]<- data.frame(percent=percent, category=category, word=word, 
  stringsAsFactors = F) #adding the information to the next row of the data.frame
  return(df)
 }

 df<-output(df,"bla","bla")
 df<-output(df,"sdfd","dfsdf")
 df<-output(df,"xfdfd","qweqweqw")
 df<-output(df,"asdad","etwt")
```

Output:

```
  #percent category     word
#1      12      bla      bla
#2      12     sdfd    dfsdf
#3      12    xfdfd qweqweqw
#4      12    asdad     etwt
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend modeling your thinking after the apply family. This way you can pass a data set to say, an apply and bind together a series of similarly structured data frames. Now I'm assuming from your example that these percentages are coming from a separate data frame so to create an example:

```
#data to reference for percent calculations
data <- data.frame(
   category = c(rep('blood',5),rep('lung',5)), 
   word = c(rep('Male',3),rep('Female',4),rep('Male',3))
   )
#input for the function
input <- data.frame(
   category = c('blood','blood','lung'), 
   word = c('Male','Female','Male')
   )
#I'll use your function you have listed with some adjustments since I don't have your
#percent function.
output <- function(category_point, word_point, data){
    row <- data.frame(
    percent = sum(category_point == data[,'category'])/length(data[,'category']) ,
    category = category_point, word = word_point,stringsAsFactors = F)
    return (row)
}
#Now execute the apply function with the input being passed and execute by row.
list_of_rows = apply(input,1,function(x) output(x['category'],x['word'],data)) 

#bind this list of similarly structured rows together.
new_df  = bind_rows(list_of_rows)
new_df

  percent category   word
1     0.5    blood   Male
2     0.5    blood Female
3     0.5     lung   Male
```

I hope this helps!

EDIT: I should also mention that if you wanted to run this again with new input then you can simply bind_rows() the result of the new input to the previous output continuously.

```
new_input <- data.frame(
   category = c('lung','blood','lung'), 
   word = c('Female','Female','Female')
   )

#Run another apply
new_list_of_rows = apply(new_input,1,function(x) output(x['category'],x['word'],data)) 

#bind this list of similarly structured rows together.
new_new_df  = bind_rows(new_df,new_list_of_rows)
new_new_df

  percent category   word
1     0.5    blood   Male
2     0.5    blood Female
3     0.5     lung   Male
4     0.5     lung Female
5     0.5    blood Female
6     0.5     lung Female
```